# Best approach to input a blog post and store related information into a database

Tags: php, mysql

I'm doing a test blog where I have 3 tables: `users`, `comments` and `posts`.

I'm having difficulties with the **posts**.

For those, instead of several text-type inputs and file upload controls, I would like to have a large textarea where I could write text and drag and drop images.

So I'm looking for a rich text component, but I don't need text markup, upload files, programming codes etc.; I just want insert plain text and images.

If my best option is using a rich text component, how can I go about extracting images from text to save in my db? Also, the number of images is unknown; how can I store a variable number of items in a MySQL database? Do I use a multiple-value column? The actual image data would be kept in a project folder, so I would only need to save the images' id or URL.

Comment: salt the content , your markup will not create an issue

Comment: keep dont understand how i will share blocks of text and images when i need inner the content in the html like order when i create the post :(, and about how i will save datas in my data base, how i create any column with multiple value

Comment: Clarified the intent (this is actually *two* questions - how to gather data, e.g. using CKEditor and its API through AJAX, and how to store it into a database (you'd best served by introducing a fourth table `pictures` (id_picture, id_post) ) in a one-to-many relationship). But I'm afraid both questions are *off topics*, and you'd be expected to show what you have tried so far.

Comment: well are a good option make a new table just for pictures, i will do this :), just i dont know how i will select the block text and images and inner in html in same order of how i to do the post like this. <block text><picture><block text><picture><picture><block text>  etc...  what i do are simple, is a form of post static, where i just select all column frm table and inner in html in a form static like <text><image><text><image> but i want a post dinamic dont static :(